# How should we tag Millennia: Altered Destinies?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have one question about this game, which is this one:

[How can I take advantage of meeting myself?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40357/how-can-i-take-advantage-of-meeting-myself)

The problem is is that the original asker tagged it with [millenniaaltereddestinies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/millenniaaltereddestinies) in order to get under the tag limit. The proper name is including spaces, and seeing as someone just edited the tag to which bumps it again, and someone else just put a bounty on it, it's likely to get a lot of visibility.

I don't think we want to set a precedent for users that removing the hyphens used for spaces in titles is an acceptable substitute in order to cram as much of the game name within the tag limit as possible.

How should we tag this game instead?

Comment: Maybe `millienia-altered`.  When are game devs going to start taking our tag limit into account?!

Comment: Actually it was originally tagged with [tag:milleniaaltereddestinies], I had to add an `n` to millennia.

Comment: HA and I typoed it too, even after googling CyberSkull's fix to confirm. Awesome :/

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up FallenAngelEyes. This is the first tag I had to create, can't believe I managed to even mispel it after trying to create a proper tag for 10 minutes :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Matthew Read's (properly spelled) suggestion, I've gone ahead and retagged the game to [millennia-altered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/millennia-altered) and submitted a tag wiki excerpt with the full game's title in it.

Answer (score 1):

**The tag name is now [millennia-altered-destinies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/millennia-altered-destinies).**

Since the tag length was [increased to 35 characters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), I've went ahead and [retagged the linked question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/40357/revisions) with the full title.